# R data frame from list of rasters by pixel count?

Tags: r

I have set of classified rasters from different years (2003,2004,2005, lets say r1, r2, r3). Tha raster classes and their proportion vary within years.

I want to make a single data frame from my list of rasters. The data frame should contain indication of raster (year/r1..), and a count of pixels per raster classes.

I know that I can get the count of pixel values per class by `table(values(r))`. How can I get the `tables` from each raster together in single data frame?

Example:

```
library(raster)

# create raster
r1<-raster(ncol= 3, nrow = 3)
values(r1)<-rep(c(1:3), 3)

#  create more rasters, assign classes
r2<-r1+1
r3<-r1

values(r3)<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1)

# create raster list
r<-list(r1,r2,r3)

# get count of pixel values
table(values(r[[1]]))
table(values(r[[2]]))
table(values(r[[3]]))

# expected to obtain:

raster class count
r1     1     3
r1     2     3
r1     3     3
r2     2     3
r2     3     3
r2     4     3
r3     1     6
r3     2     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to get the desired results with your list r:

```
lst <- lapply(r, function(x) as.data.frame(table(values(x))))
df <- cbind.data.frame(raster=paste0('r', rep(1:length(r), sapply(lst, nrow))), 
                       do.call(rbind, lst))
names(df)[2:3] <- c('class', 'count')
df

   raster class count
1     r1     1     3
2     r1     2     3
3     r1     3     3
4     r2     2     3
5     r2     3     3
6     r2     4     3
7     r3     1     6
8     r3     2     3
```

Answer (score 3):

Another similar solution via the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- bind_rows( 
      r1 = as_data_frame(table(values(r[[1]])))
    , r2 = as_data_frame(table(values(r[[2]])))
    , r3 = as_data_frame(table(values(r[[3]])))
    , .id = "raster"
) %>%
# because I assume you want integers instead of strings
mutate( class = as.integer(Var1) ) %>% 
select(raster, class, count = n)
```